# Angular 6 and typescript import a class with properties in component

Tags: html, angular, typescript, components

I have a `ProductButton.ts` class

```
export class ProductButton{

    public ProductBtnID: string;
    public ProductID: string;
    public ParentWfTaskID: string;
    public WfTaskID: string;
    public TaskName: string;
    public ButtonText: string;
    public ImageContentID: number;
}
```

I'm trying to import this into my component and create new instances of it.
But I can't seem to create new instances of it.

here is my component class

```
import { ProductButton } from '../../models/ProductButton';

@Component({
    templateUrl: './product-edit.component.html',
    providers: []
})
export class ProductEditComponent implements OnInit {

    constructor(){}

    addChildTask(){
        if(!this.product.ProductButtons)
            this.product.ProductButtons = [];

        var pButton = new ProductButton();
        pButton.ButtonText = "";
        this.product.ProductButtons.push(pButton);
    }
}
```

Why I try to new up an instance of `ProductButton` I get an empty object with no properties. How do I create a new instance every time I hit that method?

Comment: You don't provide any of those properties, there's no constructor to initialise them and the types only exist at compile time. What did you expect as output?

Comment: @jonrsharpe You're right I wasn't that familiar with TS. I didn't think of initializing it like a JS class. I don't see many examples on this online.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When your `ProductButton.ts` is compiled you will get something like this in vanilla JavaScript.

```
// Without any properties
var ProductButton = /** @class */ (function () {
    function ProductButton() {
    }
    return ProductButton;
}());
```

To answer your question you will need to initialize each property in the class.

**ProductButton.ts**

```
export class ProductButton {
    public ProductBtnID: string;
    public ProductID: string;
    public ParentWfTaskID: string;
    public WfTaskID: string;
    public TaskName: string;
    public ButtonText: string;
    public ImageContentID: number;
    constructor() {

        // Init properties as empty strings
        this.ProductBtnID = "";
        this.ParentWfTaskID = "";
        this.WfTaskID = "";
        this.TaskName = "";
        this.ButtonText = "";
        this.ProductID = ""

        // Init as O becuase type number
        this.ImageContentID = 0
    }
}
```

However, if you just wanted to validate the class/object's properties I would recommend using a typescript `interface`. Interfaces describe the public side of the class.

**ProductButton.ts**

```
export interface ProductButton {
    ProductBtnID: string;
    ProductID: string;
    ParentWfTaskID: string;
    WfTaskID: string;
    TaskName: string;
    ButtonText: string;
    ImageContentID: number;
}
```

**ProductEditComponent.ts**

```
import { ProductButton } from '../../models/ProductButton';

@Component({
    templateUrl: './product-edit.component.html',
    providers: []
})
export class ProductEditComponent implements OnInit {

    constructor(){}

    addChildTask(){
        if(!this.product.ProductButtons)
            this.product.ProductButtons = [];

        var pButton: ProductButton = {
            ProductBtnID: "942u52r",
            ProductID: "AAA12",
            ParentWfTaskID: "ww12223",
            WfTaskID: "242122",
            TaskName: "My Favorite Task",
            ButtonText: "Complete your favorite task!!!",
            ImageContentID: 234212342,
        }

        this.product.ProductButtons.push(pButton);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, as per @jons comment this is what I did.

Answer (score 1):

You should write a constructor for your `ProductButton.ts`

```
constructor(productBtn: any) {
  this.ProductBtnID = productBtn.ProductBtnID;
  this.ProductID = productBtn.ProductID;
  // ... rest of the properties.
}
```

Then in your component you can create objects of the above class like:

```
let prBtn = new ProductButton(obj)
```

where `obj` is the object containing attributes.